# Problema al tratar de descifrar si un número es primo o no - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo este programa para determinar si un número es primo o no. Todo funciona bien, si coloco uno me dice que no es primo, si coloco 2 me dice que es primo, si coloco un número par me dice que no es primo, si coloco un número como 21 me dice que no es primo; pero cuando coloco el 5 o 7 no aparece el console.log que dice que es primo.

He revisado el código y no encuentro nada... Alguien me ayuda?

```js
var numero = parseInt(promptNum("Introduce un número"));
if (numero <= 1) {
  console.log("número no válido");
}
else if (numero == 2) {
  console.log("es primo y par");
}
else if ((numero % 2 == 0)) {
  console.log("no es primo, pero si divisible entre 2");
} else {
  var primo = true;
  for (var i = 3; i<=Math.sqrt(numero) && primo; i+=2) {
    if (numero%i==0) {
    primo = false;
    }
    if (primo == true) {
    console.log("Es primo"); 
    } else {
    console.log("No es primo");
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Según puedo notar no te muestra nada porque cuando realizas el `Math.sqrt()` del número `7` el resultado es `2.6457513110645907` y como en tu `for` inicializas `i=3` tu validación en éste seria `3 < 2.6457513110645907` y como esto es **falso** nunca entrará.

Ahora bien lo que yo haria es separar el método para verificar si el número es primo y retornar un `boolean` para que cuando el número módulo 2 se identifique que es 0 retorne un `false` directamente. Modificando un poco tu código seria de la siguiente manera:

```
var numero = parseInt(promptNum("Introduce un número"));
if (numero <= 1) {
  console.log("número no válido");
}
else if (numero == 2) {
  console.log("es primo y par");
}
else if ((numero % 2 == 0)) {
  console.log("no es primo, pero si divisible entre 2");
} else {
    if (esPrimo(numero) == true) {
      console.log("Es primo"); 
    } else {
      console.log("No es primo");
    }
}
function esPrimo(num) {
    var m=Math.sqrt(num);
    for (var i=2; i<=m; i++) {
        if (num%i==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos

Comment: Gracias crack!!